# Transaction direction Row Over Partition minipulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have transactional data from our Time and Attendance Clocking system that I have to calculate the total Hours in zone with. So I created a query using row over partition to do this.

It works fine if the users use their clock cards correctly (meaning the directions follow e.g. in,out,in,out..etc). But because we cant always rely on the user to do that we get data like this:

```
MSTSQ   DATE        DIRECTION   TIME
-----   ----------  ---------   ------------
61      2013-03-12  IN          07:56:43.000
61      2013-03-12  OUT         09:58:19.000
61      2013-03-12  IN          10:16:05.000
61      2013-03-12  OUT         12:08:10.000
61      2013-03-12  OUT         12:08:11.000
61      2013-03-12  IN          12:08:11.000
61      2013-03-12  IN          12:11:04.000
61      2013-03-12  OUT         13:45:28.000
61      2013-03-12  IN          13:45:29.000
61      2013-03-12  IN          13:50:38.000
61      2013-03-12  OUT         16:28:11.000
61      2013-03-12  IN          16:28:12.000
```

My sql statement works as follow:

```
WITH TIME_LIST
AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TD.MSTSQ, TD.DATE ORDER BY TD.ID) RN
        , TD.MSTSQ
        , TD.DATE
        , TD.DIRECTION
        , TD.TIME
FROM TRANSACK_DETAILS TD
)

Select 
  currul.MSTSQ
, currul.DATE
, Convert(datetime, prevul.TIME - currul.TIME,108) [Time In Zone]
FROM TRANSACTIONS 
INNER JOIN TIME_LIST currul ON currul.MSTSQ = TRANSACTIONS.MST_SQ  
    AND TRANSACTIONS.EVENT_DATE = currul.DATE
INNER JOIN TIME_LIST prevul ON currul.MSTSQ = prevul.MSTSQ 
    AND currul.DATE = prevul.DATE AND currul.Rn+1 = prevul.Rn
```

My result then looks like this:

```
MSTSQ   DATE        Time In Zone
-----   --------    ------------
61      20130312    02:01:36.000
61      20130312    00:17:46.000
61      20130312    01:52:05.000
61      20130312    00:00:01.000
61      20130312    00:00:00.000
61      20130312    00:02:53.000
61      20130312    01:34:24.000
61      20130312    00:00:01.000
61      20130312    00:05:09.000
61      20130312    02:37:33.000
61      20130312    00:00:01.000
```

Now I need to change the statement to only calculate the time between the IN and OUT (Time In Zone) Directions.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select tin.MSTSQ
  , [DATE] = tin.[DATE]
  , INTIME = tin.[TIME]
  , OUTTIME = tout.[TIME]
  , DURATION = datediff(ss, tin.[TIME], tout.[TIME])
from times tin
  outer apply (select top 1 *
              from times tout
              where tin.MSTSQ = tout.MSTSQ
                and tin.[DATE] = tout.[DATE]
                and tin.[TIME] < tout.[TIME]
              order by tout.[TIME]) tout
where tin.DIRECTION = 'IN'
  and (tout.DIRECTION IS NULL or tout.DIRECTION = 'OUT')
order by tin.MSTSQ
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dee54/2).

Here's one way of doing it. I've made one guess at how to handle missing data, but this can be updated as required.

I understand this might be pseudo table names, but it's probably worth noting that using reserved T-SQL words is bad form and you should consider combining the date and time column if possible.